# VIM: Change current highlighted search term matched with /search

Tags: vim

Is there any command equivalent to "delete until the end of the current highlighted search match and enter insert mode"?

For example, I search for a term with:

`/Element`

It finds the string `ExampleElementExample`, places the cursor on the E in Element, and highlights `Element`.

I would like a generic command that applies to all searches that is equivalent to `c7l` or `ctE` in this particular case. However, I also want to be able to easily repeat this command to the next match by pressing `n`, `.`.

`c//e` basically does what I want, but falls short because it replaces the current search buffer, so `n` no longer takes me to the next match. Right now I'm using `ctE` or visual mode, but I feel like there must be a better option.

What is the fastest and most efficient way to execute this command?

Comment: I think `c7l` or `cft` (do not use `ctE`, since `E` is not guarantee) plus any editing + `ESC` just works fine. It's can be repeated with `n`, `.`s.

Comment: That's what I've been using, but the disadvantages are having to take a second to count letters for `c7l`, and `cft` doesn't capture the entire string in some cases, such as "PurchaseStatus". For something like that I use `vfs;c`, but it seems like there should be a shorter command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Vim is recent enough (7.3 with a patch-level above 6xx), you can use `gn`:

```
barbazfoobazbar

/foo<CR>

barbaz[foo]bazbar

cgnvim<CR>

barbazvimbazbar
```

You can hit `.` to jump to the next `foo` *and* change it to `vim` in one go.

See `:help gn`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option would be to use search and replace with the confirm flag.

```
:%s//replace/gc
```

If you leave the search string empty, it will automatically use the current search string. By the `c` flag, it asks you for permission to replace and upon decision, it will move to the next match. The `g` flag will find all matches, not just the first on a line, which I hope is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom text object taken from [Copy or change search hit](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_or_change_search_hit) on the Vim Tips Wiki:

```
" Make a simple "search" text object.
vnoremap <silent> s //e<C-r>=&selection=='exclusive'?'+1':''<CR><CR>
    \:<C-u>call histdel('search',-1)<Bar>let @/=histget('search',-1)<CR>gv
omap s :normal vs<CR>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted; thank you. With this in my .vimrc, I can simply type `cs` to change the selected text, and it still preserves the search so I can push `n.` to repeat the action on the next match.